# Find a complete solution to the difference equation $y_{n+2} + 2y_{n+1} - 3y_n = 2 + 2n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

Find a complete solution to the difference equation
$$y_{n+2} + 2y_{n+1} - 3y_n = 2 + 2^n$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please, show your attempt/working.

Comment: @user730049 2n or 2^n ? Title is different from text.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I am sure that you already solve the case of

$$y_{n+2} + 2y_{n+1} - 3y_n =0$$

Now, since this is a linear recurrence equation, if
$$y_{n+2} + 2y_{n+1} - 3y_n = P_k(n)$$ where $P_k(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, the particular solution must be a polynomial $Q_{k+1}(n)$ that is to say
$$y_n=Q_{k+1}(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} a_i\, n^i$$ Just replace and identify the coefficients $a_i$.